# CRAN package with an optional dependency

Tags: r, v8, cran

I built a R package whose some functions use the `V8` package. But `V8` is not supported on some platforms, so I want to make these functions available only for the platforms supporting `V8`. How to deal with this situation? I can put `V8` in the `Suggests` field of `DESCRIPTION` instead of the `Imports` field, and test whether it is available with `requireNamespace`, but then how do I deal with the functions that must be imported from `V8`? I want to submit this package to CRAN.

Comment: Hmm [this](https://github.com/react-R/reactR/blob/6d00dd22f92e3f281589f5834b7bef4365daf267/R/babel.R) looks like a solution. No import, just `V8::...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution by copying the way used by the `reactR` package.

- Put `V8` in the `Suggests` field.
- Do not import `V8` or its functions in `NAMESPACE`; use `V8::...` to use the `V8` functions.
- In the functions requiring `V8`, use `requireNamespace` to check whether `V8` is present, and throw a message or an error if it is not:

  ```
  if(!requireNamespace("V8")){
    message("This addin requires the 'V8' package.")
    return(invisible())
  }
  ```

I ran `R CMD CHECK` and it did not complain.

Comment: If anybody wonders why `requireNamespace` but not `require` (as me), here is an excerpt from Hadley's [R Packages](https://r-pkgs.org/namespace.html):  
"Use `requireNamespace("x", quietly = TRUE)` inside a package if you want a specific action (e.g. throw an error) depending on whether or not a suggested package is installed. ... You never need to use `require()` (`requireNamespace()` is almost always better),..."

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution in my opinion is to have two packages. The first package (`A`) would contain all of your code that does not depend (directly or indirectly) on `V8`. The second package (`B`) would depend on the `A` and contain all of your code that does require `V8`.

```
                              +-------+
                              |       |
                              |  V8   |
                              |       |
                              +---^---+
                                  |
                                  | Requires
                                  |
         +-------+            +---+---+
         |       |            |       |
         |  A    <------------+  B    |
         |       |  Requires  |       |
         +-------+            +-------+
```

On platforms that support `V8` then users can take `B` and on all other platforms users can take `A`.

Package `A` could `Suggest` package `B`.